# Unable to play Age of Empires: Rise of Rome over LAN in Windows 10

Tags: wifi, age-of-empires

In Age of Empires: Rise of Rome, when you create a server, it provides you with the IP address you have to set in the Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4) of the Wireless Network Connection Properties, by selecting the option '*Use the following IP address*'.

The IP address that I have set it is not showing up in Age of Empires: Rise of Rome - instead, it shows two IP addresses, as can be seen in the image below:

[image]

The above image shows Age of Empires: Rise of Rome installed on Windows 10.
I have also tried these settings in Windows 7, where the game was able to successfully connect to the IP address which I had set in the Wireless Network Connection Properties.

The IP address settings which I used:

[image]

The Windows 7 installation of Age of Empires: Rise of Rome, which was able to successfully connect:

[image]

But in Windows 10 it is showing those two different IP addresses, instead of the IP address which I have configured for it.

Does anyone know why this happens, or how I can adjust the settings so I can start hosting games?

Comment: I edited your question - if you don't agree with any change, feel free to adjust them. I presumed you want to host local multiplayer games.

Comment: Yes I want to host age of empire locally any suggestions for the solution?

Answer (score 3):

Since Rise of Rome connects successfully with **Windows 7** and this latter is obviously connected through local ip `192.168.0.11` which is the ip for `"Wireless network connection"`

Now the The reason for you are seeing two local ips in **Windows 10** is that you have two network connections enabled. And rise of rome is picking two local ips from two network connections but most definitely only using the first ip on that list.

Only keep "**Wireless network connection**" which is your Wifi internet But disable the rest.

[image: disable network connections]

**Windows 10 & Windows Defender**

Windows 10 comes with an integrated Antivirus(Windows Defender) + Windows Firewall. So you must add your game exe file to both [Windows Defender](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4028485/windows-10-add-an-exclusion-to-windows-security) + [Windows Firewall](https://lexisnexis.custhelp.com/app/answers/answer_view/a_id/1081611/~/adding-exceptions-to-the-windows-firewall). Doing so ensures that the game won't be interrupted or slowed down or blocked.

**An Observation**

> The screenshot you took for windows 7 static ip shows a different
>   local ip format `192.168.0.X` which means your gateway or router
>   address should be `192.168.0.1`. Your local PC ip (based on your
>   image) is `192.168.0.11`.
>
> So make sure your windows 10 local ip address is of the same format
>   too.
>   And do not leave the **Default Gateway:** empty. Fill it with `192.168.0.1`